# Read an Excel file from a Link in PHP or CURL

Tags: php, excel, curl

I have a client project in which I have to read an excel file from following link:
`https://app6.bosch.de/cgi-bin/WebObjects.dll/V5Prod_WES6.woa/39/wo/UpG9CtiiPkkyvA2ECwgqkg/41.0.1.3.21.1.1.9.9.0.2.27.3.17.7.1`

Everytime a new link is generated, when we click on this link in normal site, it opens in a new tab an excel download option.

How to read the same file from my website using PHP (e.g. using curl)? I want to read this file and save it in my website directory automatically.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please consider this topic [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make it easier to help you.

Comment: Thank you hassan for good reply.

Comment: @hassan do you have some idea about it?

Comment: no, you need to try something and back with your tries if there is any issues with those tries.

Comment: @hassan okay I'll get back